# Is there a way to find UI elements from an Android app using another android app?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, testing

For example, maybe the user can choose the app from the ones that are installed on the device or the ones that are currently running in the background. Or maybe inspect the current page of the app running in the background, for example inspect the register page of Facebook app, then login on Facebook and inspect the home page of it.
Something like the Uiautomator but running on android..